# Running python scripts using autostart

Tags: raspbian, python, lxterminal

How can I make my python scripts load and run one time once the desktop loads?

I've put the python scripts into *.sh* files

Ive edited autostart and called them using

```
@lxterminal -e "./start.sh"
@lxterminal -e "./start2.sh"
```

And yes added them before

```
@xscreensaver
```

right now both scrpits loop although they shouldn't.

If I remove the *@*  or do *--command* not *-e* I have  same issue of the scripts looping

Here is my start.sh

```
/bin/sh
vncserver
cd /home/pi
sudo python led.py #makes led flash 5sec on 5 sec off twice then end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside this folder:

```
 ~/.config/autostart
```

Add a file with `.desktop` extension. Below is the basic structure for `yourapp_autostart.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/YOUR_APPLICATION/your_app.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=YOUR_APPLICATION
Comment=
```

Ofcourse adjust the names of the file and scripts to your liking.

Comment: Thanks... Is it best to make a folder in `/usr/bin` or best to call from `/home/pi`?

Comment: You should be able to run your files from `/home/pi` no problem. However in terms of best practice I don't know myself.

Comment: Is there a way to make it start once the dektop starts. My python script has a gui elemnet and is not shown wih way above?

Comment: THIS is the way to make it start once the desktop starts. If you're having trouble with it you might want to have a look at changing some settings in that file

Comment: Sorted thanks was missunderstood how it worked but i see now